# Cannot authenticate my Service Account on Google Drive API

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

Please, be patient, it's my first question posted here on StackOverflow and so I'm not exactly sure what is the best way to describe my problem.
Ah, and also I apologize in advance for my english. ;)

This is the short version: despite the fact it seems I did all the things Google advises to do, I still can't upload or download files from Drive.
I am using Visual Studio and Google.Apis.Drive.v2, and I'm trying to use a Service Account because it's the web server who has to upload the files in the remote folder.
All the examples and samples use the CLIENT_ID/CLIENT_SECRET mechanism and that's why it's really difficult for me to understand what's going on and why and how I'm failing.

This is what I did:

- I registered my application in the Google Developers Console
- I gave the authorization to the Client ID to use
  *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive* inside the Security section into my domain.
- I downloaded the security certificate .p12 and I putted it in a public folder

... then I wrote this to create a Drive Service object:

```
public static DriveService GetDriveService(string PrivateKey, string ServiceAccountEmail, string Username, string ApplicationName)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(PrivateKey, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
             new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(ServiceAccountEmail)
             {
                Scopes = new[] { 
                DriveService.Scope.Drive, 
                DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                DriveService.Scope.DriveAppsReadonly,
                DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts,
                DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,
                DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly},
                User = Username
             }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
        return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName
        });
    }
```

... and in the asp.net MVC controller (just to try) I putted this:

```
string PrivateKey = @"PATH/XXXXX.p12";
string ServiceAccountEmail = "thatloooooongstrangenumerseccecc@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
string Username = "XXXXXXX";
string ApplicationName = "XXXXXX";

DriveService service = ImageHelper.GetDriveService(PrivateKey, ServiceAccountEmail, Username, ApplicationName);

if (service != null)
{
    FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
    request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false";
    FileList files = request.Execute();
}
```

... but the point is that I get always this:

> An exception of type 'Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException' occurred in Google.Apis.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error:"access_denied", Description:"Requested client not authorized.", Uri:""**

Any idea?

Comment: Most likely this error is thrown when the client ID dosen't have access  in the admin console. To do so, You need to give your service-account access to your domain first. Here is the link on how to give domain wide delegation https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account .Let me know if you still have issues

Comment: I did it! it's the second bullet point in my checklist.

Comment: Hope you have added the scopes in the One or More API Scopes section while giving domain-wide authority to your service account. Please check on the setup steps:  During setup in the Admin console you have to use the Client ID which looks like somestring.apps.googleusercontent.com, for ServiceAccountCredential you have to use the Email address which looks like somestring@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: Yes, exactly! I used that *insanemess*.apps.googleusercontent.com to register with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive